# Incorrect syntax near '1': STUFF and QUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following is my code and I get "Incorrect syntax near 1", the 1 being the one in the SELECT @cols statement. Can someone please tell me what the error is?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE OnCall_Report 
(
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime,
    @SID varchar(10)
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(CategoryName)from OnCall_Category FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ,1,1,'');


SELECT @query=' 
        SELECT 
                EmployeeSID,
                ManagerSID

            FROM
                (
                SELECT EmployeeSID, 
                       ManagerSID,
                       IsAllowance*10+AllowanceCategory as Category,
                       Count(RequestID)as RequestCount   

                FROM 
                       OnCall_Request 

                WHERE 
                        EmployeeSID='+@SID+' and 
                        RequestDate BETWEEN '+convert(varchar(200),@FromDate)+' AND '+convert(varchar(200),@ToDate)+' 

                GROUP BY 
                         EmployeeSID,
                         ManagerSID,
                         IsAllowance,
                         AllowanceCategory
            )

            PIVOT (
                     Min(RequestCount) 
                     FOR Category IN ('+@cols+') 
                   ) AS t2'
Execute(@query) 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `where` clause.

```
WHERE 
    EmployeeSID='+@SID+' and 
    RequestDate BETWEEN '+convert(varchar(200),@FromDate)+' AND '+convert(varchar (200),@ToDate)+'
```

`EmployeeSID` is a string, so would need to be quoted, and the dates are dates, so likewise.

It would be better practice and safer to use `sp_executesql` and pass these values as parameters to your dynamic SQL.